# Solving equations with maxima

Tags: trigonometry, symbolic-math, maxima

I can solve the equation bellow normally

```
sin(b1*(x-c1)) = sin(b2*(x-c2))
b1*(x-c1)      =  b2*(x-c2)
c2             = x-(b1*(x-c1))/b2

for c1 = 0, b1 = 1, b2 = 1.5, x = pi/2

c2 = (x-(b1*(x-c1))/b2) = 0.523598775598299
```

But when I try and do this in Maxima see below the answer is completely different what am I doing incorrectly?

```
kill(all)$
numer:true$
phase1:0; freq1:1; freq2:1.5; x:pi/2; solve(sin(freq1*(x-phase1))=sin(freq2*(x-phase2)),phase2);
```

Answer I get below
[image: Answer I get]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`solve` usually works only for simple equations, try `Solver`.

Also, `pi` (variable) is not the same as `%pi` (constant).

```
kill(all)$
load(solver)$
numer:true;
f:sin(freq2*(x-phase2))=sin(freq1*(x-phase1));
phase1:0; freq1:1; freq2:1.5; x:%pi/2; a:Solver([f],[phase2]);
rhs(a[1][1]),numer;
```

Answer: **0.5235987755982978**

Your second question:

```
kill(all);
f:sin(b1*(x-c1)) - sin(b2*(x-c2))=0;
triginverses:all;
solve(f,c2);
```

Comment: Thanks is there a way to get maxima to show the equation it used to get the answer.  `c2 = (x-(b1*(x-c1))/b2)`